# extjs - grid column render fail

Tags: extjs, rendering, extjs4.1

I'm having a problem rendering a column.

The column in question should show an error image or a success image, and while doing the validation should show a loading gif. Everything was working perfectly, until the test with more than 40 records, and then the error occurred. Basically the error is that it is not loading neither the image nor the gif loading.

The process is very simple, for each record an AJAX query is done. This query creates a pdf file and returns the name of that file. After creating all the pdfs files are made the union of the files and shown on the screen.

I tried to simulate the error with a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2atr), but in the fiddle the error does not occur. 
The only difference between the fiddle and the application is that in the fiddle the `timeout` has been added to simulate the response time of the AJAX request.

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dEKy.png) of the correct form when the error does not occur.
[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk5mb.png) of when the error occurs, does not show the gif `loading`.
[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csvLk.png) of when the error occurs, does not show the image `apply`.

In the images with the error you can verify that the tags are correct with the image or gif added, however it is not updating the screen.

Detail, in the browser Edge (40.1) works perfectly, this error is occurring in Chrome (63) and Firefox (Quantum). No testing in older versions.

Another detail is that only occurs with the images and with the gif, the texts of the other columns are all with the information updated correctly.

Below is the fiddle code:

```
 var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
     storeId: 'simpsonsStore',
     fields: ['name', 'email', 'icon', 'phone'],
     data: [{
             "name": "Test",
             "email": "email@test.com",
             "icon": "1",
             "phone": "33333333333"
         },
          .
          .
          .
         {
             "name": "Test",
             "email": "email@test.com",
             "icon": "1",
             "phone": "33333333333"
         }
     ]
 });

 var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
     title: 'Simpsons',
     store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
     columns: [{
             header: 'Name',
             dataIndex: 'name',
             width: 200,
             editor: 'textfield'
         },
         {
             header: 'Email',
             dataIndex: 'email',
             width: 300,
             editor: 'textfield'
         }, 
         {
            header: '',
            dataIndex: 'icon',
            sortable: true,
            menuDisabled: true,
            width: 30,
            align: 'center',
            renderer: function (value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                var returnValue = '';
                //
                switch (value) {
                    case '1':
                        returnValue = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/H9ezVYF.png" style="cursor:pointer;"  width="13" height="13">';
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        returnValue = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/g2bz2ak.png" style="cursor:pointer;"  width="13" height="13">';
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        returnValue = '<img src="https://i.imgur.com/z7gwGoJ.gif" style="cursor:pointer;"  width="13" height="13">';
                        break;                        
                }
                //
                return returnValue;
            }             
         },
         {
             header: 'Phone',
             dataIndex: 'phone',
             width: 200
         }
     ],
    viewConfig: {
        markDirty: false
    },     
     dockedItems: [{
        dock: 'top',
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Load Rows',
            autoEl: { tag: 'center' },
            iconCls: 'x-tbar-loading',
            handler: function () {
                //
                // 
                for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
                    //
                    var record = store.getAt(i);
                    record.beginEdit();
                    record.set('icon', '3');
                    record.endEdit();
                }
                //
                for (var i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
                    //
                    var dt = new Date();
                    console.log('for 1 -> ' + i + ' : ' + dt.getHours() + ':' + dt.getMinutes() + ':' + dt.getSeconds())
                    //
                    // Here instead of time out has an AJAX request
                    setTimeout(myFunction, ((i + 1) * 1000), i);
                }
            }            
        }]         
     }],
     selType: 'rowmodel',
     height: 650,
     width: 800,
     renderTo: Ext.getBody()
 });

function myFunction(i)
{
    var dt = new Date();
    console.log('for 2 -> ' + i + ' : ' + dt.getHours() + ':' + dt.getMinutes() + ':' + dt.getSeconds())
    //
    var record = store.getAt(i);
    record.beginEdit();
    record.set('icon', '2');
    record.endEdit();
}
```

Comment: why dont you just load the complete store with updated records? seems pretty bad to make ajax calls per row... also is the call sync? if async you cant use the "i" for the serveranswer... (cant tell without seeing ajax code). Edit: theres more: why do you use 2 for-loops instead of doing both in one loop? why 49 and not storeitemcount?

Comment: It is the business rule to monitor each call. Yes it's call sync! Yes it is possible to use a loop only, I used two to clarify the process, first load the gif, after the image